# Horizontal scroll move step by step

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling, swipe-gesture

I'm developing an android app that User select an emoticon.
I'd like a nice swipe gesture selection with horizontal scroll.
can i create a horizontal scroll to select emotion.

this is an example

https://www.dropbox.com/s/n298h17r3fs2wvj/scrollswipe.jpg

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768930/implementations-of-emoji-emoticon-view-keyboard-layouts

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener`?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html

I think onScroll() is just vertical, but I might be wrong; onFling() is definitely horizontal but requires a bit of velocity.

If you haven't looked at GestureDetector, then you should write a simple demo for yourself with it in any case.

On the jpeg it looks like you are after a very specific hook like curve.  If that's the case, then you need to implement detection yourself using the lower level, more flexible `View.OnTouchListener`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

Comment: Gestures are simple the problem is layout. I want creare an horizonalscrollview with 3 emoticon for portion screen but it is impossible.

see image

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tndb34qt6gb8uy4/hscrollemoticon.jpg

i'd like recreate central horizontal scroll with 3 icone every screen and move 1/3 when user swipe